# Validating e-mail username and password using try/catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm trying to write a code that validates an email as a username and a password that has at least one uppercase, one lowercase, and one special character. When I run the program, I'm getting "Successfully signed up." no matter what I input. I believe my error is in my try/catch block.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class UserSignUp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String username;
            String password;

        try {
            System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
            username = input1.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
            password = input2.nextLine();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully signed up.");
    }

    public static void validateUsername(String username) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String pattern = ".+@.+\\.com";
        if (username.matches(pattern)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid username.");
        }
    }

    public static void validatePassword(String password) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        boolean isUppercase = false;
        boolean isLowercase = false;
        boolean isDigit = false;
        boolean hasSpecialCharacter = false;
        char ch = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
                isUppercase = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain an uppercase letter.");
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                isLowercase = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain a lowercase letter.");
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                isDigit = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain a digit.");
            }
            if (!Character.isDigit(password.charAt(ch)) && !Character.isLetter(password.charAt(ch))) {
                hasSpecialCharacter = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain a special character.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Successfully signed up.")` should be *inside* the `try`, as the last statement. You also need to actually call your validation function, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to it, the explanation is already embedded:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserSignUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // No need for two scanners, one scanner can accept multiple (also
        // multiple-lined) inputs.
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            // Put validation inside the try block.
            // Regarding there are no other use of the variables, it is unnecessary to give
            // the two variables "Method Level Scope" instead of "Block Scope".
            System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
            String username = in.nextLine();
            validateUsername(username);
            System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
            String password = in.nextLine();
            validatePassword(password);
            // Put the println() inside the try block.
            System.out.println("Successfully signed up.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public static void validateUsername(String username) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String pattern = ".+@.+\\.com";
        // If not matches the pattern,
        if (!username.matches(pattern)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid username.");
        }
    }

    public static void validatePassword(String password) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        boolean isUppercase = false;
        boolean isLowercase = false;
        boolean isDigit = false;
        boolean hasSpecialCharacter = false;
        char ch = '\0';

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            ch = password.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                isUppercase = true;
            if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
                isLowercase = true;
            if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                isDigit = true;
            // ch is already defined as a character.
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch) && !Character.isLetter(ch))
                hasSpecialCharacter = true;
        }

        // Ask for the constraints after read through all characters.
        if (isUppercase != true)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain an uppercase letter.");
        else if (isLowercase != true)
            // Fix the error message of lower-case letters.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain a lowercase letter.");
        else if (isDigit != true)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain a digit.");
        else if (hasSpecialCharacter != true)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password must contain a special character.");

    }
}
```

Hope this answer helps and please leave this question as it is as someone might need it, unless there is important changes.

Comment: You should fix some of the other problems in the original question instead of repeating them, e.g. the two Scanners, the unnecessarily wide scope of username and password, the mistaken error message when no lowercase character is present...

Comment: @tgdavies You're right, I only ensured that the function runs fine, but did not fix other problems. Let me modify it again.